# Можно ли проверить в JUnit, что вернётся именно то значение которое мы ожидаем?

Tags: java

а именно:  one, two, three, не больше и не меньше

```
public class streamExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

    stringList.add("ONE");
    stringList.add("TWO");
    stringList.add("THREE");

    long count = countStrings(stringList);

    System.out.println("count = " + count);

}

public static long countStrings(List<String> stringList) {
    Stream<String> stream = stringList.stream();

    return stream
            .map((value) -> { return value.toLowerCase(); })
            .count();
}
```

}
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам не помог ни один из ответов на ваш предыдущий вопрос?

Comment: Добавляйте к названиям тестовых методов `test` в начале или в конце и не будете путаться.

Answer (score 2):

Вы всё правильно делаете, за исключением того, что в `assertEquals` вы рекурсивно вызываете тестовый `countStrings`, вместо вызова статического метода `streamExample.countStrings`, т.е. должно быть так:

```
assertEquals(4, streamExample.countStrings(testStringList));
```

Если вы хотите проверить именно содержимое testStringList, можно использовать другие `assert` методы, например:

```
assertArrayEquals(new String[]{"A","B","C","D"}, testStringList.toArray());
```